# When via a class method get an object, why before return the value, the method can put the value into AutoReleasePool?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

e.g.

method1:

```
-(void)method1{
id array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//now,retainCount of array1 is 1
}
```

method2:

```
-(void)method2{
id array2 = [NSMutableArray array]; //now,retainCount of array2 is 2
}
```

question 1:
Int method2,the Implementation of class Method +array  is not use [alloc [init]]? But why it did not return value directly?And put the value in AutoReleasePoll?

question 2:
Which is better (faster & more efficient) to use between the two way? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these statements are equivalent and the second one doesn't actually add to the retain count of `array1`. With the first method your function would assume ownership and would subsequently be responsible for any release calls later on, but with ARC you don't have to worry about these details.

In pre-ARC days, values that methods would return would be put in autorelease pools to avoid premature deallocation and memory leaks. Consider the following cases:

```
-(NSArray *)emptyArray {
    // create return value with calls to alloc and init.
    NSArray *returnArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    return returnArray;
}
```

Because there is no call to [returnArray release]; the value returned by this method will never be deallocated and thus there will be a memory leak. At first it may seem like there is no direct solution to this.

```
-(NSArray *)emptyArray {
    NSArray *returnArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    return returnArray;
    [returnArray release]; // unreachable statement
}
```

and

```
-(NSArray *)emptyArray {
    // create return value with calls to alloc and init.
    NSArray *returnArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [returnArray release];
    return returnArray; // will return deallocated object
}
```

So we instead add the array to the autorelease pool so that it will be released after some time--long enough for it to be retained by whatever is receiving the return value, but still ultimately preventing any memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC, there is no mater which ever you like to use. both are same.

If you are not using ARC, For method1 you have to call release by your own and method 2 is autoreleased object.

```
[NSMutableArray array] = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease] // Both having same retain count = 1
```